# Swift - ViewDidAppear called from another class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I have a simple application with two views. When I launch to the home view the `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` are called. When I go to another view in my application it calls `super.viewDidLoad` and calls the func, but it also calls `viewDidAppear` from the home view. I can't find any commands to call it (Searched entire code base). What could be causing this extra call?

*** ADDITIONAL TESTS ***

I added break points to find the issue.

1) home calls: viewdidLoad, then viewdidappear

2) click link to detailview

3) this calls deatailview viewdidload which calls super (aka home) view did load

4) home view did load finishes and then home viewdidappear is called

5) error in home viewdidappear

Any ideas why home viewdidappear was called afterwards?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and watch.

Comment: @DarkDust I updated the question after working with breakpoints

Comment: are you going back to the main menu again

Comment: No, somewhere after detailView super.viewDidLoad -> home[aka super] viewdidAppear is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, 'home' is the super class of your 'detail' view controller " ***deatailview super (aka home)*** ". 
You either haven't implemented the viewDidAppear or called super.viewDidAppear in the 'detail' vc , hence the superclass' (home vc's) viewDidAppear is executed.

Comment: I have not implemented viewWillAppear. I've also never heard of it. I'll look it up

Comment: Sorry. I meant 'viewDidAppear' the method which is being called. Edited my answer. In any case you must learn about all the view controller lifecycle methods.

Comment: The solution was that I could easily accomplish the task by making them separate view controllers (not child, parent). This eliminated the problem of calling the parent. Now to clean up my code

Answer (score 0):

Parent class Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Child Class Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Explanation

Home class is super Class and Child class is sub class when ever super class view is loaded for the first time it calls viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear of super class.
When we click on the link it moves to detail view there it calls viewDidLoad(sub class)->viewDidLoad(super class) and viewDidAppear(sub class)->viewDidAppear(super class)